# Angular/Ionic HTTP response data different from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've hit a snag and I'm hoping you guys can help:

I have a basic HTTP get in Angular - I've done it 100 times at this point. My JSON response on the server, confirmed, is formed like so:

```
[{"date":"07\/24\/2017","time_start":"02:00 PM","time_end":"05:00 PM","name":"Adult Ministries Registration","room":"","speaker":"none","speaker_writein":"","xhead":"yes"}]
```

You see the final property is "xhead" and it's a string "yes" or "no" - which I'm using to determine when to show titles that break up events by day (grouping them by time under a date in a schedule list).

The problem for me is that when this data comes into the Angular app, "xhead" is undefined. I'm doing a simple console.log on the response data and it shows as undefined.

Even more odd is that if I change these values to 1 or 0, they all come into Angular as either 1 or 0 - not differentiated as they should be for each item in the collection (response).

When i visit the endpoints in the browser, the data is as it should be.

Help!!! I'm losing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though using ng-if="response.xhead=yes" in the view changes the value of the item. That was the problem.

***The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.***

Comment: Thanks @MrJSingh for the additional info - that info was what led me to test the ng-if to see if it caused the problem.